# How to run menu items of Excel via VSTO add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am developing an Excel 2013 VSTO project. I need to execute existing menu items (e.g., File->Export operation).

How can I do it? I've tried to search for examples but didn't find any.

Comment: If you wish to execute commands on Excel which can be fired via the User Interface, probably able to do so via the Object Model.

Comment: @MacroMarc: Do you know of a tutorial or example that shows how to use the object model?

Comment: I don't know that there is a legend to show you every possible button and its code, but I've always found if you record a macro, run the menu command and then look at the VBA code, it gives you 95% of what you need.  The VBA translates pretty cleanly to C# in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is the VBA page for the ExportAsFixedFormat method of the Worksheet Object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat . There are all sorts of functionality to call from Excel Object Model, and that page has more info than the Interop Pages.

You can call the Excel Object Model through your VSTO usually like:

```
//inside a function call from your VSTO project
Excel.Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
string exportMessage = await SaveASPDFAsync(ws, @"C:\Test\.test.pdf", false);
//more code - if empty string, it was a good export
```

A method might look like this:

```
private async Task<string> SaveASPDFAsync(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws, string filepath, bool openAfterPublish)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            bool originalDisplayAlerts = ws.Application.DisplayAlerts;
            try {
                ws.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type: Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Filename: filepath, OpenAfterPublish: openAfterPublish);
                ws.Application.DisplayAlerts = originalDisplayAlerts;
                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        });
    }
```